# Why don't my images show up properly on the front end?

Tags: javascript, java, image, web-applications

I am developing a web application for a university project but I'm having trouble displaying images on the front-end. The below Java code is being used to process images on the back-end:

```java
private byte[] getImageBytes(String directoryPath, String id) {
   FilenameFilter filter = (dir, name) -> name.matches("^" + id + "\\b.*");
   File directory = new File(directoryPath);
   File[] matchingFiles = directory.listFiles(filter);

   if (matchingFiles == null) {
      return null;
   }

  try (FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(matchingFiles[0])) {
       byte[] fileData = new byte[(int) matchingFiles[0].length()];
       fis.read(fileData);
      return fileData;
  } catch (IOException e) {
       System.out.println("File could not be read: " + e.getMessage());
      return null;
  }
}
```

The resulting byte[] is then given to an object annotated with @XmlRootElement and then returned to the front-end.

On the front-end, I use the following code to receive and process the images:

```js
let imageElement = document.createElement("img");
let fileData = news.image;
let uint8Array = new Uint8Array(fileData);
let base64String = btoa(String.fromCharCode.apply(null, uint8Array));
imageElement.src = 'data:image/jpeg;base64,' + base64String;
```

The `news` object is a JSON object with the `image` key, which contains the byte array generated from the earlier processing.

However, when I append the `imageElement` to the designated location, the image is not displayed correctly. The image appears as shown:

[image isn't displayed correctly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DNGsF.png)

Can anyone help me understand what I might be doing wrong or if there are any other pieces of code that I might be missing? Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: have you console logged fileData to make sure it is not empty?

Answer (score 0):

You can't do like that. You have to convert filepath to uri. And get base 64 from uri on android process.

Don't do convert base64 on front end. Just complete the base 64 string format by adding "data:image/jpeg;base64," into base64 string that have been processed on android before.